# The value of $\sum ij$, where the summation is over all $i$ and $j$ such that $1 \leq i \leq j \leq 10$

Tags: summation

> The value of $\sum ij$, where the summation is over all $i$ and $j$ such that $1 \leq i \leq j \leq 10$, is
>
> 1. 1320
> 2. 2640
> 3. 3025
> 4. None of the above

How do I organise the numbers so that I can make this extensible for any arbitrary $n$ and not just 10?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reorganize the sum as

$$
\sum_{1\leq i\leq j\leq n}ij=\sum_{j=1}^n j\sum_{i=1}^j i=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{j^2(j+1)}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^nj^3+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^nj^2=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{8}+\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{12}
$$

Comment: But the answer given is $1320$ and not $1705$ as your formula provides. :/

Comment: Nevermind. Your answer is correct. I tested it using a simple Java program. The answer *is* 1705.

Comment: You get 1320 with the condition $1\leq i<j\leq n$.  In other words, $i$ is *strictly* less than $j$ rather than $i$ is less than or equal to $j$.

Comment: Oh. Silly mistake on my end.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**

Let $$S=\sum_{1\le i< j\le 10}ij$$
observe that
$$(1+2+\ldots+10)^2=1^2+2^2+\ldots+10^2+2S$$
The sum you are looking for is
$$\sum_{1\le i\le j\le 10}ij=S+1^2+2^2+\ldots+10^2$$

Comment: What happened to the last line? It's a bit confusing.

Comment: In the last line, the inequality $<$ became $\leq$.  What happens is that in the product $(1+2+\cdots+10)^2$ you get both $2*3$ and $3*2$.  Since $i\leq j$, we'll collect those and divide by $2$.  Unfortunately, the squares like $3*3$ appear only once, so we'll need to add new a new set of squares so that we double them up and can divide by $2$.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**
Let $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n i$. Then,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j = i}^n ij
= \sum_{i=1}^n i \sum_{j = i}^n j
= \sum_{i=1}^n i (S_n - S_{i-1})
= S_n \sum_{i=1}^n i - \sum_{i=1}^n i S_{i-1}
= S_n^2 - \sum_{i=1}^n i S_{i-1}
$$
Can you find $S_n$ and finish the simplification?